# Failed to read data using reinterpret_cast<char*> in C++

Tags: c++, file, c++11, fstream, reinterpret-cast

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

// write file

    string file_name = "random_fstream.dat";
    ofstream file(file_name, ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);

    if (!file) {return EXIT_FAILURE;}

    int r = 2; 
    int c = 3;

    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&r),sizeof(r));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&c),sizeof(c));

//------------------------------------------------

// read file

    ifstream in(file_name, ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    if (!in) {return EXIT_FAILURE;}

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x),sizeof(x));
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&y),sizeof(y));

    cout << x << y << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to practice write and read file in **C++**. First step was to write int value 2 and 3 into the file with binary form. Second step was to read the two number from that file.

Then I got x and y valued both equal to 0, but I expected to receive `x=2` and `y=3`. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you deliberately trying to read from the same file while it has not been closed after the write operations? Or is that an oversight?

Comment: Also, you are reading into `x` twice instead of reading into `x` and `y`.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.. Let me edit it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As have been pointed out in comments, you have at least two bugs:

The first problem is in your reads: both your reads use the address of `x` and the size of `y`, which I'm sure is just a typo.

Second, you have to `close()` the file you opened for writing (or at least, *flush* your writes (`sync()`) before reading that same data again, but that needs a whole lot of caution and special rules.) Anyways, you need to close the file, either by letting the handle (`file` in this case) fall out of scope and getting its destructor called, or calling `file.close()` yourself (after the writes.)

To prevent this problem, you generally have to check for errors *every time* you do any I/O. To do that, you can use the name of your file handle like a boolean variable, e.g.:

```
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x),sizeof(x));
if (!in)
    cerr << "First read failed." << endl;
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&y),sizeof(y));
if (!in)
    cout << "Second read failed." << endl;
```

I you want to know what actually is going on, the class `std::istream` has an explicit conversion to `bool` that returns whether the last operation succeeded or not (or whether the stream is in a readable/good condition or not.) There is also a host of member functions defined for C++ streams (both input and output) that help you check for errors, the end of a stream, etc., e.g. `bad()`, `good()`, `fail()`, `eof()`, etc.

Again, just remember that any I/O operation can fail at any time for various reasons, so check its status!